# Multiple level category drop-down

Tags: categories, themes, cms

I'm using WordPress as a CMS and would like to have categories selectable from multiple selections i.e `<option>`.

[image][image]

As a usage example, The first dropdown would contain parent categories. Then after selecting the parent a second select drop-down would appear with the child categories. There are a few plugins available on Wordpress.org but they all seem to be broken or out of date. Any help would be appreciated.

Broken plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-category-dropdown/

The code I'm using from wordpress.org

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/" method="get">
    <?php
    $select = wp_dropdown_categories('orderby=name&echo=0&depth=0&hierarchical=1&exclude=5,4');
    $select = preg_replace("#<select([^>]*)>#", "<select$1 onchange='return this.form.submit()'>", $select);
    echo $select;
    ?>
    <noscript><input type="submit" value="View" /></noscript>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function parent_child_cat_select() { ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        /* <![CDATA[ */
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {     
                jQuery('#parent_cat').change(function(){
                    var parentCat=jQuery('#parent_cat').val();
                    // call ajax
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url:"/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                        type:'POST',
                        data:'action=category_select_action&parent_cat_ID=' + parentCat,
                        success:function(results)
                        {
                        jQuery("#sub_cat_div").html(results);
                        }
                     });
                });         
            });     
        /* ]]> */
        </script>

        <form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/" method="get">

        <div id="parent_cat_div"><?php wp_dropdown_categories("show_option_none=Select parent category&orderby=name&depth=1&hierarchical=1&id=parent_cat"); ?></div>

        <div id="sub_cat_div"><select name="sub_cat_disabled" id="sub_cat_disabled" disabled="disabled"><option>Select parent category first!</option></select></div>

        <div id="submit_div"><input type="submit" value="View" /></div>

        </form>
<?php }

function implement_ajax() {
    $parent_cat_ID = $_POST['parent_cat_ID'];
    if ( isset($parent_cat_ID) )
    {
        $has_children = get_categories("parent=$parent_cat_ID");
        if ( $has_children ) {
            wp_dropdown_categories("orderby=name&parent=$parent_cat_ID");
        } else {
            ?><select name="sub_cat_disabled" id="sub_cat_disabled" disabled="disabled"><option>No child categories!</option></select><?php
        }
        die();
    } // end if
}
add_action('wp_ajax_category_select_action', 'implement_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_category_select_action', 'implement_ajax');//for users that are not logged in.

//this is optional, only if you are not already using jQuery  
function load_jquery() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');            
}     
add_action('init', 'load_jquery');
```

For displaying the the drop-down menus use the `parent_child_cat_select()` function.

```
<?php parent_child_cat_select(); ?>
```

Comment: add_action('wp_ajax_category_select_action', 'implement_ajax');//for users that are not logged in. Should be add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_category_select_action'. 'implement_ajax' );

Comment: @Wild Phoenix yes you are right. I fixed it in my post.

Comment: Thanks! However, I'm getting a message that's indicating there are no child categories when there are several.

Comment: @Zach do you have posts assigned to these child categories? Also be aware this setting will list only strictly related sub-categories.

Comment: @JohnnyPea Yep, each has several custom posts. I'm ok with it listing strictly related categories. For instance Camera would have each of the categories that I've assigned products to. I updated the post with a shot of what my categories section looks like. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Zach Do you use caching plugin? Did you test it in another internet browser? (try to clean you cache) Did you copy my code as it was? (try to copy the code again) Don't you have some plugins or theme functions which could interact with categories or somehow filter them? - you can try to deactivate all the plugins and set the default theme and check if it works...it is working for me with no active plugin and default theme TwentyTen

Comment: Nope, I've never installed on here. Yep, tested it in the three different browsers. I killed all of my site's plugins. I'll test it on another site to see if I can figure out the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="<?php echo remove_query_arg(array('mycat_go', 'cat')); ?>" method="get">
    <?php
    // get selected category and do some initializations
    if (isset($_REQUEST['cat'])) $_REQUEST['mycat_go'] = $_REQUEST['cat'];
    $selected = $_REQUEST['mycat_go'];
    $selects = array();
    $last = 0;
    $top = false;
    $i = 0;
    // basically, we are looping from the selected up through the parents
    // till we have no parent anymore.
    while (!$top) {
        // prep query to generate field containing all child categories
        // of the selected one
        $args = array(
            'name' => 'mycat_'.$i,
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'echo' => 0,
            'hierarchical' => 1,
            'exclude' => '4,5',
            'child_of' => $selected,
            'depth' => 1,
            'show_option_none' => '--select--',
            'hide_if_empty' => true,
        );
        if(!empty($last)) $args['selected'] = $last;
        // prepare next loop iteration or stop if we are displaying children of 0
        if (!empty($selected)) {
            $last = $selected;
            $category = get_category($selected);
            $selected = $category->parent;
        } else {
            $top = true;
        }
        // generate output and store in reversed order as we are going bottom up
        $select = wp_dropdown_categories($args);
        $select = preg_replace("#<option([^>]*)>#", "<option$1 onclick=\"this.parentNode.name = 'mycat_go';return this.form.submit()\">", $select);
        array_unshift($selects, $select);
        $i++;
    }
    // print to screen
    foreach ($selects as $select) {
        echo $select;
    }
    ?>
</form>
<form action="<?php remove_query_arg(array('mycat_go', 'cat')); ?>" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="cat" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['mycat_go']; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go there" />
</form>
```

Could use some polishing, but should work.

Comment: lol, that was pretty impressive and it totally makes sense! However there's an error on line 15 `if(!empty($last) $args['selected'] = $last;` I'm not sure what's causing it.

Comment: @Zach Shallbetter: Oops, that's a typo...missing closing bracket. Edited it.

Comment: So I went ahead and added it to the page and it returned an uncountable list of select boxes. It also had a huge load time. I thought it might be me so I nuked a few categories and wiped all other code off of the template. Didn't seem to resolve the issue.

Comment: @Zach Shallbetter: Looks like the loop condition doesn't grab and it keeps on looping. Ok...i made another edit that should avoid the loop from going endlessly when no initial selection is made.

Comment: Seems to only show a single select box with the child values. Also, when you select an item it doesn't perform an action.

Comment: @Zach Shallbetter: Sorry, my original loop condition came from a different initial approach and then i didn't think properly about it. I edited again and added some comments, i hope this works better.

Comment: @Zach Shallbetter: The JS problem should be resolved now, too.

Comment: I apologize for running you around. The result I'm getting is the same as I had originally when I used the code from codex. I add information to the category and the category appears in the select. I select it and it takes me to the page. I think the problem may lie in the fact that the drop-down doesn't show empty categories.

Comment: Also, it doesn't matter if the child has a parent, all that will appear in the select is the child.

Comment: I added `'hide_empty' => 0` to the array and that allowed me to see all categories including empty ones. Doesn't show a secondary select though when choosing a parent just goes directly to that page.

Comment: @Zach Shallbetter: Yes, i didn't think of that, of course it would, as it's parsing the 'cat' url parameter. I did another edit that should (hopefully) avoid that...sorry for running you around, too. ;-)

Comment: Wish this thing would let me post images, lol. So selecting an item now shows absolutely every post. It also doesn't show a second select when I add `'hide_empty' => 0` to see the parent categories and select one of those. I haven't seen the second select yet. Problem with using `'hide_empty' => 0` though is that it show every single category instead of just parents (if that makes sense).

Comment: @Zach Shallbetter: Lol...ok, for a change, i finally tested it locally, set up a few categories and so on. Now...it works, kinda. There's a few issues. Dunno how well it behaves with `hide_emtpy`, but the basics work.

Comment: Still no secondary selection, Is there something on my end that would cause this?

Comment: Yeah, when I select the category in the select it takes me to the entire list of entries falling under it.

Comment: @Zach Shallbetter: Argh, this is not my day at all...something went wrong when pasing the code back in. Make sure it's 2! separate forms (the last bit was missing).

Comment: Also consider that this is really more like a quick shot for inspiration. It should be done in a better way, like reloading only that form bit with AJAX is better than reloading the whole page and when there's a single entry it should be auto-selected etc. .

Comment: If you replace your whole code bit with the whole code bit above, it should not forward to the categories page anymore.

Comment: Gosh, I simply don't know what I'm doing wrong here. I've created a completely basic page. I add an exact copy of the code above. When I select "models" from the select (it has 4 subs). It immediately jumps to /?mycat_go=112 without showing a secondary selection. Thanks again for all of your help wyrfel.

Comment: Maybe there's a misunderstanding...it is supposed to reload the page with that parameter. That's how it works. It's not AJAX or JS driven. It just reloads the page given the selected category as a parameter and then redraws itself on page load.

Comment: Ahh, i think i get it...it must be the `action` parameter in the forms...see edit.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I've tried a couple times now and haven't gotten it working properly. When I select a category from the select it hangs and doesn't refresh showing the secondary selection.